# Populate a postgres table from multiple csv files in a folder

Tags: postgresql, powershell, csv, automation

I have about 300 csv files in a folder all of exactly the same format.

I need to import them into a postgres SQL table just appending them all.  In future I would be getting a new one each week so I'm trying to automate this process.

I am currently trying to do this from within PowerShell but not having much luck.  Has anyone done anything like this before?  Should I be using powershell or is it possible from within PgAdmin or postgres?

Cheers,

GPC

Comment: Look at the [copy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) command, which you can run from psql directly.

Comment: For the ongoing append, you can use pgagent, which you can install from the Application Stack Builder (assuming you're on Windows).